# "Facebook error: Application is not visible to this person."

Tags: android, ios, facebook, ionic2

I am using Facebook invite in my IONIC 2 app. I am getting this error, When I click "app invite button" in my app.

> "Facebook error: Application is not visible to this person."

Could anyone help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you tried invite someone with the same facebook account, from which you have created app on facebook ?

Comment: Is your facebook app still in development? Could be that the user you tried to invite has no role set in the facebook application (developer, tester etc).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today with exactly the same error message.
I have an ionic 1 app using the appInvite function in the cordova-plugin-facebook4.

It started working again after doing updates of ios and android platforms and plugins. 
I can not pinpoint what actually made it work again, but among the plugins I updated were inappbrowser and facebook4.
For facebook4 I actually copied the android source from the github repo to the plugin directory.
Remember to remove and add the platforms after updating the plugins.